# Make Target name Swift flag visible in UITests module (Swift 5)

Tags: swift, xcode, module, frameworks, uitest

I have more than one target in the project and a lot of code shared between all Target.

[image: s]

I want to make `-D $(TARGETNAME)` visible in UITests and be able to `@testable import enum TargetFirst.MyEnum` from root project (`MyEnum` is used in all Targets)

what should be in UITest's file:

```
#if TargetFirst
    @testable import enum TargetFirst.MyEnum
#elseif TargetSecond
    @testable import enum TargetSecond.MyEnum
#endif
```

Of course I can create separate file for each Target but I want to avoid code duplication.

Is it possible to do? If yes, what did I miss and how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can add **Active Compilation Conditions** under **Build Settings** for your targets.

> Active Compilation Conditions is a new build setting for passing
>   conditional compilation flags to the Swift compiler.

```
import XCTest

#if FirstTarget
   // ..
#else
   // ..
#endif
```

[image]

Comment: as `Other Swift Flags` `Active Compilation Conditions` works in the root project, but doesn’t in UITests target :(

Comment: Actually when you update "Active Compilation Conditions" in your root project, It is also updated in your uitest target by default. Can you check whether they are same? If so, you should be able to use it.

Comment: I just double checked it with hardcoded string and with $(TARGETNAME) snd still not working. Did I miss something?
Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, I tested to use in my test target like I share in the snippet above. What is the error you got?

Comment: just code inside #if #endif block unacceptable, no matter what I put inside this block. 
I can describe what I did: 
(1) added $(TARGETNAME) in `Active Compilation Conditions` in TargetFirst and TargetSecond
(2) try to use #if FirstTarget flag inside `UITest`'s target file (that available in TargetFirstUITests and TargetSecondtUITests)